# Poisson regression on parts of a total count

Tags: r, poisson-regression

My dataset contains data like the total amount of deaths in different countries. Then I have as columns indicating smaller parts of the total amount specifying the cause of the death. I have another column with a continuous variable indicating the wealth of the nation. For example:

| Nation | Total | By_car_incident | Suicide | Homicide | Nation_Wealth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| France | 50 | 20 | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| Italy | 70 | 35 | 20 | 15 | 27 |

Now, I am interested in the effect of the nation wealth on each cause of death. I was thinking to first make the dataset long and have one column with cause and number of deaths.

| Nation | Cause | Number | Nation_Wealth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| France | By_car_incident | 20 | 30 |
| France | Suicide | 10 | 30 |
| France | Homicide | 20 | 30 |
| Italy | By_car_incident | 35 | 27 |
| Italy | Suicide | 20 | 27 |
| Italy | Homicide | 15 | 27 |

Hence, I was thinking of a Poisson regression to predict *Number ~ Nation_Wealth:Cause* using glm(),  but I get that every interaction is significant with extremely low sig. levels, there is a Nagelkerke R^2 = 100% and the assumption of over-dispersion is violated.  Do you see any potential problem on testing in my reasoning?  Am I reasoning wrongly? Can I find other modellization strategies to describe the effect on Nation_Wealth on each cause of death? I apologize in advance for the non-reproducibility of the dataset, but I just want to know if the test and modeling strategy is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

- You'd likely need an offset term in your model for population, as the more persons you have, the more deaths. In a standard `glm` in R the `offset` would be `log(population)`.
- Poisson overdispersion can come from a variety of sources. Here I suspect it's partly due to missing an offset term. It can also come from missing a predictor, or simply that Poisson is not a good descriptor of this count data - you could try a negative binomial instead.
- I'm not convinced that using Cause of Death as a predictor is very useful, or meaningful. Perhaps three models, one for Homicide, one for Car etc.?

Comment: Thanks for the clear comment! Would it make sense to include the total of deaths as offset? And a second question: can I safely fit models for each cause (I have a total of 7 causes)? I have been told that repeating tests on the same predictor and  on the same sample is likely to inflate the risk of Type I-error and I may consider correcting my alpha-value. Sorry for the newbie questions…

Comment: Q1 - I think no. The number of deaths is the response variable, what you're modelling. Unless you had a scenario like "I know there are $N$ deaths total, how many do I expect to be attributable to cause $K$", I think you're actually interested in modelling $N_K$, the total number of deaths attributable to cause $K$. Q2 - sure. Yes, fitting lots of models increases your Type I error rate, so you may want to do a Bonferroni correction. But what are you actually interested in? p-values are not the be all and end all, models can also be fit using AIC, used to descriptively explore data etc.

Comment: wonderful explanation! Thanks